# Minimize Ribbon to Just Tabs using Excel 2003 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in Excel 2003 to minimize ribbon to just tabs (show tabs) using VBA?

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
```

or

```
SendKeys "^{F1}", False
```

do not work in Excel 2003.

and

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", False)"
```

completely hide ribbon.

Comment: The first 2 should work, or do you get any errors? Test if pressing Ctrl + F1 works to minimize the ribbon. That should work  in Excel 2007 / 2010 / 2013 / 2016 / 2019 as you can see in teh documentation [Show or hide the ribbon in Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-the-ribbon-in-office-d946b26e-0c8c-402d-a0f7-c6efa296b527)

Comment: @PEH They do not work and Ctrl + F1 do nothing.

Comment: @PEH Sorry. This is an .xls Workbook; Excel 2003 not 2007. But if it is saved as .xlsm this commands or Ctrl + F1 do not work.

Comment: OK, I did some research: The documentation is correct and Ctrl + F1 or `SendKeys "^{F1}", False` works in Excel 2007. `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"` does not work it was introduced in 2010. I got this confirmed in 2 different places [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/minimize-ribbon.981093/) and [here (sorry german)](https://www.herber.de/forum/archiv/1440to1444/1441549_Ribbon_minimieren_funktioniert_nicht.html) • Note that Excel 2003 has no ribbons therefore you cannot hide them (the file type is not relevant here just the Excel version).

Comment: @PEH The wokbook was created as Excel 2003 file but opened in Office 2007. Now, I saved it as .xlsm to try if it works. So now it is a 2007 file. But 'SendKeys "^{F1}", False' opens Help sometimes and Ctrl + F1 do nothing.

Comment: As I told the file type is not relevant (only the Excel version you use right now). And documentation and 2 sources tell that `SendKeys "^{F1}"` (which is just Ctrl + F1) work. If it does not work for you, you did something wrong that we cannot see, or your installation is not correct, or … • If the help opens that means you (or sendkeys) only triggered `F1` but not the `^` which is `Ctrl`. Check your installation, do a restart of your computer. This has to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Excel 2003 does not have the Ribbon, the code shown in the question cannot work in Excel 2003. The first suggestion will, additionally, trigger errors in Excel 2003 - Excel 2003 does not have the method `CommandBars.ExecuteMso`.